# Confidence interval for difference of mean

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

According to my study, the confidence intervals for the difference in means provide a range of likely values for the difference between 2 population means. If 95% confidence interval for the difference of 2 sample means include null value, we can claim that there is no statically significant difference between the two groups.

For this comparison, do two populations need to be equivalent? Or can it be two different populations?

(Actual problem: I have test data collected from 2 test scenarios, where the settings of each test is different from each other. I want to compare the two mean values obtained from them. Note that the two distributions do not have normal shape (bell shape))

Comment: what you mean by saying "equivalent populations"?

Comment: This is what I mean. Assume you do a sample test with several conditions. Then you do another sample test using another set of invariants. In that case two populations are not equivaluent right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have described in your first paragraph assumes normality of datasets. So, if it is reasonable to make such assumption for the data collected in each of your scenarios then you can apply normal confidence interval method.

Comment: No. In my datasets, original data doesn't have normal distribution. But according to central limit theorm, we can assume that mean values have a normal distribution, right?

Comment: if the number of observations in each group is sufficiently large then yes.

Comment: you can additionally plot the [KDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) of each sample and compare the resulting plot with normal density.